# In Belgium or from where to buy this grill over rack, steamer rack?

Tags: chicken, grilling, microwave, shopping

I have this microoven which has grill functionality. But to grill chicken like following picture:

[image]

i do not have that stand (steamer rack) which is holding the chicken on top.

Do you know in Europe/US/UK/Asia where i can buy this online to get delivered in Europe?
i tried in bol.be , http://www.coolblue.be/ but not found any.

Please advise where to get one.

Comment: Hello and welcome! What you have here is actually a steamer rack for use in a wok or pot. I bought mine at an Asian food store. They come in a variety of sizes so you want to find one that will fit your microwave plate. I think you will find it very easily with a search or possibly locally if you have an Asian food store nearby.

Comment: Have you tried amazon?

Comment: In Belgium you cant use Amazon always, most of the vendors do not delivery to Europe. We have Ebay where i searched but could not find anything. Any alternative please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to put a metal rack in the microwave? Sounds too risky to me.

Comment: The Amazon sites from the UK, France and Germany do sometimes ship to Belgium.